# Pushing data to shopping cart; cart is always showing that it's empty

Tags: database, flutter, cart, shopping-cart, sqflite

I have been attempting to add a shopping cart to my coffee app. When you press the 'one-time purchase' button, no data is pushed to the cart. My little error animation always plays in the emulator and the cart is always showing empty.

Here is my cart model:

```
class Cart {
  late final int? id;
  final String? productId;
  final String? productName;
  final int? initialPrice;
  final int? productPrice;
  final ValueNotifier<int>? quantity;
  final String? unitTag;
  final String? image;

  Cart(
      {required this.id,
      required this.productId,
      required this.productName,
      required this.initialPrice,
      required this.productPrice,
      required this.quantity,
      required this.unitTag,
      required this.image});

  Cart.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)
      : id = data['id'],
        productId = data['productId'],
        productName = data['productName'],
        initialPrice = data['initialPrice'],
        productPrice = data['productPrice'],
        quantity = ValueNotifier(data['quantity']),
        unitTag = data['unitTag'],
        image = data['image'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'productId': productId,
      'productName': productName,
      'initialPrice': initialPrice,
      'productPrice': productPrice,
      'quantity': quantity?.value,
      'unitTag': unitTag,
      'image': image,
    };
  }
}
```

Here is my product model:

```
class CoffeeItem {
  const CoffeeItem(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.image,
      required this.description,
      required this.image2,
      required this.quantity,
      required this.productPrice,
      required this.unit});

  final int id;

  final String title;
  final String image;
  final String description;
  final String image2;
  final int productPrice;
  final int quantity;
  final String unit;

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'price': productPrice,
      'image2': image2,
      'image': image,
      'quantity': quantity,
      'unit': unit,
    };
  }
}
```

Here is my item list, which is in its own file:

```
List<CoffeeItem> availableCoffees = [
  const CoffeeItem(
    id: 1,
    title: 'Roaster\'s Choice',
    image: 'lib/assets/Roasters_Choice.png',
    description:
        'Every delivery, you will receive a new and different surprise bean. This is for the coffee connoisseur that generally loves coffee no matter where it\'s from and how it\'s roasted.',
    image2: 'lib/assets/CostaRicaTub.png',
    productPrice: 15,
    quantity: 1,
    unit: '12oz',
  ),
  const CoffeeItem(
    id: 2,
    title: 'Brazil',
    image: 'lib/assets/Brazil.png',
    description:
        'Brazilian coffee is what started it all for Good Vibes and it still holds true to brewing a fantastic cup. This is our most lightly roasted coffee and has tasting notes of caramel with a little bit of nuttiness to it. This bean was grown in the Matas de Minas region of Brazil at an altitude of 1100m and was natural processed.',
    image2: 'lib/assets/Brazil Tub.png',
    productPrice: 15,
    quantity: 1,
    unit: '12oz',
  ),
  const CoffeeItem(
    id: 3,
    title: 'Colombia',
    image: 'lib/assets/Colombia.png',
    description:
        'Our Colombian coffee has the most traditional coffee flavor profile of any of our beans. It is chocolatey and robust; a perfect cup of morning Joe. These beans were grown in the Huila region of Colombia at altitudes of 1500m - 1900m.',
    image2: 'lib/assets/Colombia tub.png',
    productPrice: 15,
    quantity: 1,
    unit: '12oz',
  ),
  const CoffeeItem(
    id: 4,
    title: 'Indonesia',
    image: 'lib/assets/Indonesia.png',
    description:
        'These beans were grown in the Sumatra region of Indonesia and then were aged in their burlap sacks for 2 years after harvest. This aging process gives the coffee a savory, smoky tobacco flavor in your brew. This is a low acid cup of coffee for those of you struggling with reflux. Indonesia is one of the only (or possibly THE only) countries that uses a wet hulling process on their beans.',
    image2: 'lib/assets/Indo tub.png',
    productPrice: 15,
    quantity: 1,
    unit: '12oz',
  ),
  const CoffeeItem(
    id: 5,
    title: 'Zambia',
    image: 'lib/assets/Zambia.png',
    description:
        'Our Zambian coffee is probably our fruitiest in flavor, tasting mildly of citrus and toasted sugar. This bean was yellow honey processed, meaning that the beans retained much of their fruit mucilage during processing, then is dried on raised beds in the sun for up to 30 days. This coffee was grown in the Norther Province on the Isanya Estate at an altitude of over 1600m.',
    image2: 'lib/assets/Zambia tub.png',
    productPrice: 15,
    quantity: 1,
    unit: '12oz',
  ),
  const CoffeeItem(
    id: 6,
    title: 'Ethiopia',
    image: 'lib/assets/Ethiopia.png',
    description:
        'Our Ethiopian coffee tastes like raspberries and cream, but somehow isn\'t overly fruity like many African beans. This is probably partly due to the washed process and the way we roast the beans. An excellent brew; this is a great place to start for those who have never had an African coffee before.',
    image2: 'lib/assets/Ethiopia tub.png',
    productPrice: 15,
    quantity: 1,
    unit: '12oz',
  ),
];
```

Here is my DBHelper:

```
class DBHelper {
  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database!;
    }
    _database = await initDatabase();
    return null;
  }

  initDatabase() async {
    io.Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, 'cart.db');
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

// creating database table
  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE cart(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, productId VARCHAR UNIQUE, productName TEXT, initialPrice INTEGER, productPrice INTEGER, quantity INTEGER, unitTag TEXT, image TEXT)');
  }

// inserting data into the table
  Future<Cart> insert(Cart cart) async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    await dbClient!.insert('cart', cart.toMap());
    return cart;
  }

// getting all the items in the list from the database
  Future<List<Cart>> getCartList() async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult =
        await dbClient!.query('cart');
    return queryResult.map((result) => Cart.fromMap(result)).toList();
  }

  Future<int> updateQuantity(Cart cart) async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    return await dbClient!.update('cart', cart.toMap(),
        where: "productId = ?", whereArgs: [cart.productId]);
  }

// deleting an item from the cart screen
  Future<int> deleteCartItem(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    return await dbClient!.delete('cart', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

My Cart Provider:

```
class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();
  int _counter = 0;
  int _quantity = 1;
  int get counter => _counter;
  int get quantity => _quantity;

  double _totalPrice = 0.0;
  double get totalPrice => _totalPrice;

  List<Cart> cart = [];

  Future<List<Cart>> getData() async {
    cart = await dbHelper.getCartList();
    notifyListeners();
    return cart;
  }

  void _setPrefsItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('cart_items', _counter);
    prefs.setInt('item_quantity', _quantity);
    prefs.setDouble('total_price', _totalPrice);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _getPrefsItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _counter = prefs.getInt('cart_items') ?? 0;
    _quantity = prefs.getInt('item_quantity') ?? 1;
    _totalPrice = prefs.getDouble('total_price') ?? 0;
  }

  void addCounter() {
    _counter++;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeCounter() {
    _counter--;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getCounter() {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _counter;
  }

  void addQuantity(int id) {
    final index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    cart[index].quantity!.value = cart[index].quantity!.value + 1;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteQuantity(int id) {
    final index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    final currentQuantity = cart[index].quantity!.value;
    if (currentQuantity <= 1) {
      currentQuantity == 1;
    } else {
      cart[index].quantity!.value = currentQuantity - 1;
    }
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeItem(int id) {
    final index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    cart.removeAt(index);
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getQuantity(int quantity) {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _quantity;
  }

  void addTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice + productPrice;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice - productPrice;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  double getTotalPrice() {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _totalPrice;
  }
}
```

My cart screen:

```
class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartScreen(this.coffeeItem, this.availableCoffees, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final CoffeeItem coffeeItem;
  final List<CoffeeItem> availableCoffees;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  DBHelper? dbHelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<CartProvider>().getData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lime,
        title: const Text('Shopping Cart'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          Center(
            child: Badge(
              showBadge: true,
              badgeContent: Consumer<CartProvider>(
                builder: ((context, value, child) {
                  return Text(
                    value.getCounter().toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  );
                }),
              ),
              animationType: BadgeAnimationType.fade,
              animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20.0),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Consumer<CartProvider>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, provider, widget) {
                if (provider.cart.isEmpty) {
                  return const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    'Your Cart is Empty',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
                  ));
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: provider.cart.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade200,
                          elevation: 5.0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              children: [
                                Image(
                                  height: 80,
                                  width: 80,
                                  image:
                                      AssetImage(provider.cart[index].image!),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 130,
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        height: 5.0,
                                      ),
                                      RichText(
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        text: TextSpan(
                                            text: 'Name: ',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                                fontSize: 16.0),
                                            children: [
                                              TextSpan(
                                                  text:
                                                      '${provider.cart[index].productName!}\n',
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold)),
                                            ]),
                                      ),
                                      RichText(
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        text: TextSpan(
                                            text: 'Unit: ',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                                fontSize: 16.0),
                                            children: [
                                              TextSpan(
                                                  text:
                                                      '${provider.cart[index].unitTag!}\n',
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold)),
                                            ]),
                                      ),
                                      RichText(
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        text: TextSpan(
                                            text: 'Price: ' r"$",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                                fontSize: 16.0),
                                            children: [
                                              TextSpan(
                                                  text:
                                                      '${provider.cart[index].productPrice!}\n',
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold)),
                                            ]),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
                                    valueListenable:
                                        provider.cart[index].quantity!,
                                    builder: (context, val, child) {
                                      return PlusMinusButtons(
                                        addQuantity: () {
                                          cart.addQuantity(
                                              provider.cart[index].id!);
                                          dbHelper!
                                              .updateQuantity(Cart(
                                                  id: index,
                                                  productId: index.toString(),
                                                  productName: provider
                                                      .cart[index].productName,
                                                  initialPrice: provider
                                                      .cart[index].initialPrice,
                                                  productPrice: provider
                                                      .cart[index].productPrice,
                                                  quantity: ValueNotifier(
                                                      provider.cart[index]
                                                          .quantity!.value),
                                                  unitTag: provider
                                                      .cart[index].unitTag,
                                                  image: provider
                                                      .cart[index].image))
                                              .then((value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              cart.addTotalPrice(double.parse(
                                                  provider
                                                      .cart[index].productPrice
                                                      .toString()));
                                            });
                                          });
                                        },
                                        deleteQuantity: () {
                                          cart.deleteQuantity(
                                              provider.cart[index].id!);
                                          cart.removeTotalPrice(double.parse(
                                              provider.cart[index].productPrice
                                                  .toString()));
                                        },
                                        text: val.toString(),
                                      );
                                    }),
                                IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      dbHelper!.deleteCartItem(
                                          provider.cart[index].id!);
                                      provider
                                          .removeItem(provider.cart[index].id!);
                                      provider.removeCounter();
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete,
                                      color: Colors.red.shade800,
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Consumer<CartProvider>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
              final ValueNotifier<int?> totalPrice = ValueNotifier(null);
              for (var element in value.cart) {
                totalPrice.value =
                    (element.productPrice! * element.quantity!.value) +
                        (totalPrice.value ?? 0);
              }
              return Column(
                children: [
                  ValueListenableBuilder<int?>(
                      valueListenable: totalPrice,
                      builder: (context, val, child) {
                        return ReusableWidget(
                            title: 'Sub-Total',
                            value: r'$' + (val?.toStringAsFixed(2) ?? '0'));
                      }),
                ],
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text('Payment Successful'),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 216, 219),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 50.0,
          child: const Text(
            'Proceed to Pay',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlusMinusButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback deleteQuantity;
  final VoidCallback addQuantity;
  final String text;
  const PlusMinusButtons(
      {Key? key,
      required this.addQuantity,
      required this.deleteQuantity,
      required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(onPressed: deleteQuantity, icon: const Icon(Icons.remove)),
        Text(text),
        IconButton(onPressed: addQuantity, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ReusableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title, value;
  const ReusableWidget({Key? key, required this.title, required this.value});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
          ),
          Text(
            value.toString(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my individual item screen where my button is to push data to the cart:

```
class BeanScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BeanScreen(this.coffeeItem, this.availableCoffees, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final CoffeeItem coffeeItem;

  final List<CoffeeItem> availableCoffees;

  @override
  State<BeanScreen> createState() => _BeanScreen();
}

class _BeanScreen extends State<BeanScreen> {
  DBHelper? dbHelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<CartProvider>().getData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    void saveData(int index) {
      dbHelper!
          .insert(
        Cart(
          id: index,
          productId: index.toString(),
          productName: availableCoffees[index].title,
          initialPrice: availableCoffees[index].productPrice,
          productPrice: availableCoffees[index].productPrice,
          quantity: ValueNotifier(1),
          unitTag: availableCoffees[index].unit,
          image: availableCoffees[index].image,
        ),
      )
          .then((value) {
        cart.addTotalPrice(availableCoffees[index].productPrice.toDouble());
        cart.addCounter();
        const snackBar = SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 113, 52, 255),
          content: Text('Item is added to cart'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        );

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        print(error.toString());
        const snackBar = SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 56, 110),
            content: Text('Item is all sold out!'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      });
    }

...

   
                          ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    const Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 194, 141))),
                            onPressed: () {
                              saveData(index);
                            },
                            child: const Text('One-Time Purchase'),
                          ),
```

Also, my item counter on my icon badge does not update in quantity with button clicks. I'm sure this is because nothing is getting added to the cart. There is more to my program, but these are all of the parts that have to do with the shopping cart.

I've re-written this thing a few times. I tried connecting everything from `dbHelper!.insert` to my CoffeeItem model instead of my Cart model. I've also changed and added information in both models to try and get them to sync up better. That's at least taken away some errors, but still, no data pushed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my main.dart:

```
 void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartProvider()),
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => CartProvider(),
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: (CoffeeList(
                CoffeeItem(
                    id: 0,
                    title: '',
                    image: '',
                    description: '',
                    image2: '',
                    productPrice: 15,
                    quantity: 1,
                    unit: ''),
              )),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you are trying to implement a shopping cart into the flutter application using the Provider package and SQLite database for storage of the data. in your code i can see you have defined the models, database helper and provider. but, it seems that the data is not being added to the cart as expected.

Follow those things to identify and fix:
Ensure that you have properly initialized your **CartProvider** and **DBHelper**. You should do this at the top level of your app, typically in your **main.dart**:
void main() {
runApp(
MultiProvider(
providers: [
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartProvider()),
],
child: MyApp(),
),
);
}
be sure that CartProvider and DBHelper instances are being used consistently throughout the app.

I see SaveData function in the BeanScren you used. please make sure
index is valid index for **availableCoffess** list. you have to add a
print statement to check if it's identifying correctly as the
selected coffee item.

```
void saveData(int index) {
  if (index >= 0 && index < availableCoffees.length) {
    // Your code to add the item to the cart
    // ...
  } else {
    print("Invalid index: $index");
  }
}
```

be sure your **DBHelper** is working correctly to insert data into database. also you can use print statements here or debug logs to check the insert method is being called and if it's inserting the data correctly.

- In the **CartScreen** please make sure that you are correctly calling
  **getData** to fetch card data when the screen is loaded. you should have
  to call **initState** method or when the screen is first displayed.

you can use **try** and **catch** exceptions in your code.

please ensure that **NotificationService.initializeNotification()** is called to your main screen. here is the example how you can do -

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService.initializeNotification();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartProvider()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

please check **pubspec.yaml** here is **geolocator** is added or not. then you can use location such as this -

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

// Inside your _BeanScreen class
Future<void> _getUserLocation() async {
  try {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    );
    setState(() {
      _latitude = position.latitude;
      _longitude = position.longitude;
    });
    _schedulePrayerNotifications();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error getting user location: $e");
  }
}
```

Comment: I understood most of what you said. This is now my main.dart;

Comment: I updated my original questions so that you could see my main.dart. I also added initState to the CartScreen and BeanScreen. However, it is still not working.

Comment: can you please share logcat?

Comment: @KRAP please check my answer again.